# How to adapt the node size to image size without breaking the shape of the graph using Graphviz?

Tags: nodes, graphviz

I am making graph using images i made, but they all have a different size. When i am building the graph without setting a specific size, the graph build different node size adapting to my images.

[image: different node size]

I am modifying the size of the image using Graphviz with the line :

```
mygraph.node("A", image="./stinkbug.png", width="100", height="100", fixedsize="true")
```

The images are way smaller than the last ones and have the same size (i censored the images used). But the nodes are too big now. I tried all the fixedsize value available (true, false and shape) and it dont work.

[image: bad not size]

In addition, it is breaking the shape of my graph ! Even if i am using the same layout (fdp) in both creation. Going from this shape :

[image: good layout]

To this shape :

[image: bad layout]

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set the **width** & **height** to 100 inches (too big).

- Continue to use **fixedsize**
- Remove the **width** & **height** attributes (or change to much smaller values)
- Add **imagescale=true** or **imagescale=both**